# Perl MCE return hash data to main process

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, subroutine

I'm trying to run Perl Many-Core Engine which works fine. But when a worker adds data to a global hash in a subroutine, this data is lost once the MCE process completes (see position of the comment below). I didn't think this would be a problem as %data is global. Any advice much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MCE;

my @symbol = ('abc','def');
my $CPUs = 1;
my %data = ();

process();

sub process {
    my $mce = MCE->new(
        input_data  => \@symbol,
        max_workers => $CPUs,
        user_func => sub {
            my ($self, $sym, $chunk_id) = @_;
            $sym = $sym->[0];
            doTask($sym);
        }
    );
    $mce->run();

    print %data; # if I check contents of %data at this line in the code, its empty
}

sub doTask {
    my ($sym) = @_;
    $data{$sym} = 1;

    print %data;
    print "\n\n";

    return;
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with MCE but the processes do not share data usually. Your %data is getting copied into the child process and in fact you modify the copy. How can you expect the child process to modify data in the parent? also it is good to "use Data::Dumper;" and then "print Dumper(\%data);" to see better what %data contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works ok using the MCE::Map model, which has an inbuilt data gathering function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MCE::Map;

my @symbol = ('abc','def');
my $CPUs = 1;
my %data = ();

process();

sub process {
    MCE::Map::init {chunk_size => 1, max_workers => $CPUs};
    %data = mce_map {doTask($_)} @symbol;
    print %data; # data exchange between the manager and worker processes works
}

sub doTask {
    my ($sym) = @_;
    $data{$sym} = 1;
    return %data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Full data sharing capability supporting deep sharing will be included with the upcoming MCE 1.7 release.

```
use MCE;
use MCE::Shared;

mce_share my %data;
```

The hash is shared between workers supporting processes and threads.

Comment: I can't get the 'mce_share my %hash;' syntax to work. It keeps throwing the error: 'Can't redeclare "my" in "my".' I found an example of a bug for this error but it appears to bear no relation to MCE that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Does doTask actually run?  It [looks like](https://code.google.com/p/many-core-engine-perl/wiki/MCE_Tasks) user_func is supposed to be part of user_tasks:

```
my $mce = MCE->new(
    input_data  => \@symbol,
    user_tasks  => [{
        max_workers => $CPUs,
        user_func   => sub {
            my ($self, $sym, $chunk_id) = @_;
            $sym = $sym->[0];
            doTask($sym);
    }]
);
$mce->run();
```

Comment: Yes, doTask runs ok. I don't think this is required unless you want to run different subroutines in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

To return or share a complex structure among all the threads, such as a hash of hash of arrary, the MCE foreach, or the MCE::Loop, with gather are tested not working. Neither do the MCE::Map. The only tested working way is via threads::share, by recursively add shared sub layers, as shown by http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=798735,  and use shared_clone for the end assignment.

```
# the following lines cannot be ommitted otherwise error "Invalid value for shared scalar"
unless (exists $HoH{$F[0]})
{
my %p : shared;
$HoH{$F[0]} = \%p;
}
# the following lines if skipped will randomly missing a few records
unless (exists $HoH{$F[0]}{$mf})
{
    my @c : shared;
    $HoH{$F[0]}{$mf} = \@c;
}  
$HoH{$F[0]}{$mf}=shared_clone([$F[3],$F[4]]);
#we cannot use $HoH{$mf}=shared_clone(\%Loss) directly, where %Loss is a hash of arrary
```

BTW, this method only work when run as standalone script, if running from within perl debugger which do not permit "use threads" before "use threads::shared", will return empty values.

Comment: the new MCE::Shared can share hash of hash of array, now we can use it to get ride of the recursive share cloning.